# List changes another list even after using answers from other questions

Tags: python, list, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a tic tac toe bot, but the the function `next_move()`, which chooses next best move, has a problem.

```
def next_move(get_pieces): # get_pieces = [["","x",""],["","",""],["","",""]]
    all_possible = []
    for i in range(3):
        il = get_pieces[i]
        for j in range(3):
            print(str(i) + "," + str(j))
            if get_pieces[i][j] == "":
                temp = get_pieces.copy()
                temp[i][j] = "o"
                print(get_pieces)
                all_possible.append(temp[:])
                temp = []
    print("")
    print(all_possible)
    print("")
    print(get_pieces)
    for k in all_possible:
        if check_win(k):
            return k
    if len(all_possible) == 0:
        draw = [["","",""],["","",""],["","",""]]
        return draw
    else:
        return random.choice(all_possible)
```

Even though I did `temp = get_pieces.copy()`, changing temp changes get_pieces by using all methods such as

```
temp = get_pieces.copy()
temp = list(get_pieces)
temp = get_pieces[:]
temp = get_pieces
```

Comment: Have you tried `deepcopy` as well? (Not sure about this because I didn't read your code, but that's another method to try.)

Comment: deepcopy? lemme try it thanks

Comment: You're only making shallow copies.  This will copy a top-level list, but not nested lists.  For your nested lists, you probably want deep copies.  Just `import copy`, then use `my_copy = copy.deepcopy(nested_list)`.

Comment: ok ill try it also

Comment: Either use `deepcopy` or reconstruct the data. `temp = [x for x in get_pieces]` as it's a list of lists then we may need to apply the `copy` to each element. `temp = [x.copy() for x in get_pieces]` which is basically what `deepcopy` does. However `deepcopy` is recursive.

Comment: omg, copy.deepcopy() worked, 3 days trying to work my head out for this, thanks guys!!